# AutocompleteTextView to EditText switch is causing some UI bugs

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I want to switch between `AutocompleteTextView` and `EditText` by pressing next on keyboard. Problem is that if I request focus to `EditText` in `onEditorActionListener`, I want to show keyboard as `EditText` is focused. But keyboard will popup for 400ms and then it will close it. Keyboard is interacting with `AutocompleteTextView's` UI closing sequence forcing this new keyboard to hide. I have problems with UI elements in Android for quite a while. I had to put delay for 300ms on each `EditText` to do UI change because previous one is cancelling it.

Hiding a keyboard is taking from 80 up to 250ms so I have to delay `showKeyboard()` function 300ms after I requested focus from another View. Also `AutocompleteTextView` is probably not only hiding keyboard but also trying to hide dropdown menu. Which can take up to 1000 - 1400ms delay to show keyboard on second View. 1800ms is sometimes still not enough to wait for all UI animations to end on previous view.

How to overcome this problem?

Example code:

```
autocompleteTv?.onEditorAction { 
    clearFocus()
    nextEditText?.requestFocus()
    app.hideKeyboard(this)
}

nextEditText?.onFocusAcquired {
     //waiting 100ms to clear focus, 250ms to hide keyboard, ??ms to hide dropdown to do another action on UI Thread
     post(delay = 1800){ app.showKeyboard() }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `hideKeyboard` in your autocomplete view if you don't want it to be hidden? I would think your first block of code doesn't need the `clearFocus` call either because you immediately request focus with the other view. And I would think the second block of code is unnecessary because an EditText automatically pulls up the keyboard when it gets focused.

Comment: It was just example. If you want to switch from autocompleteTextView to Spinner you have to hide keyboard and and then performClick action to open dropdown menu. And second part, it is not working. If I request focus without these lines of codes just request focus it will never ever pulls up keyboard. Thats why i haveto do it manually.